# Angular Ui-Grid Date Format tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'd like to Show a tooltip in a Name Column of a UI-Grid something like:

```
   columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'MemberName', dispalyName: 'Member Name', 
            cellTooltip: function (row, col) {
                return 'Total Hous of ' + row.entity.MemberName + ' at the end of ' +  row.entity.date;
            }
        }
```

`

how can I change the format of row.entity.date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the $filter reference in your controller.  Then just use the [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter/) to format the date.

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', '$filter', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants, $filter) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableSorting: true,
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'MemberName', dispalyName: 'Member Name', 
              cellTooltip: function (row, col) {
                  return 'Name: ' + row.entity.name + ' Company: ' + $filter('date')(row.entity.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
              }
        }
      ]};
  }]);
```

I added a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2HyKDc27TLQDyA633u7?p=preview) sample as well.